# Add infinite scroll and pagination to custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have a custom UITableViewCell with UICollectionView inside. I would like to an add infinite scrolling to this collectionView inside Cell. But from unknown reason infinite scroll handler is called only once...

Pseudocode of my cell:

```
class CahnellsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
            
    
    public private(set) var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    class var reuseIdentifier: String { return "EpgTvChannelsTableViewCell"}
    private var channelCell: EpgTvChannelsCollectionViewCell!
    private var tvChannelList: [(PBBTvChannelMediaModel, PBBAccessStatusInfo)]?
            
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        prepare()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func prepare() {
        configureCollectionView(flowLayout: configureCollectionViewFlowLayout())
    }
    
    private func configureCollectionView(flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout) {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        collectionView.register(EpgTvChannelsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: EpgTvChannelsCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        appendSharedConstrainst(constraints: [
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
        bindInfiniteScroll()
    }
    
    private func configureCollectionViewFlowLayout() -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        return collectionViewLayout
    }
    
    private func bindInfiniteScroll() {
        collectionView?.infiniteScrollTriggerOffset = 300
        collectionView?.infiniteScrollIndicatorView = createInfiniteScrollIndicatorView()
        collectionView?.infiniteScrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = true
        collectionView?.addInfiniteScroll { [weak self] _ in
            print("JJP infinite scroll called!!")
            // function to get more data is called here
        }
        collectionView?.setShouldShowInfiniteScrollHandler { [weak self] _ -> Bool in
            //check if can download MORE
            return true
        }
    }
    
    private func createInfiniteScrollIndicatorView() -> UIView {
        let infiniteScrollIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.large)
        infiniteScrollIndicatorView.color = UIColor.Control.normal
        return infiniteScrollIndicatorView
    }

    func setTvChannelList(data: [(PBBTvChannelMediaModel, PBBAccessStatusInfo)]?) {
        //this fucntion is called when we receive data (appended data from all pagination)
        tvChannelList = data
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Generally this block of code inside handler is called only once:

```
collectionView?.addInfiniteScroll { [weak self] _ in
            print("JJP infinite scroll called!!")
            // function to get more data is called here
        }
```

I removed some part of code to make it easier to read. Do you have any suggestion why above block of code is called only once? Could you explain it to me? Also infiniteScrollIndicatorView is shown only once.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

When we received nee data we have to add 'collectionView?.finishInfiniteScroll()', otherwise above block of code is not called.

so for it works when i add *collectionView?.finishInfiniteScroll()* here:

```
func setTvChannelList(data: [(PBBTvChannelMediaModel, PBBAccessStatusInfo)]?) {
        //this fucntion is called when we receive data (appended data from all pagination)
        tvChannelList = data
        collectionView?.finishInfiniteScroll()
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```